# open a server in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to display (android/ios) 360 tour with react-vr but for doing that I need to open the tour in a WebView component using server request url, but all the packages that I have found do not work or return the same bug:

[react-native-static-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-static-server)

[react-native-http-bridge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kingstinct/react-native-http-bridge)

[here you can find my problem with react-native-static-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949285/react-native-static-server-bug-evaluating-fpstaticserver-stop)

so even if I follow the tutorial and I respect all the rules the local server does not work and shows me this bug.

[image]

This is the code off app.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'; import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native'; import StaticServer from 'react-native-static-server'; let server = new StaticServer(8080); // Start the server server.start().then((url) => { console.log("Serving at URL", url); }); server.stop(); type Props = {}; export default class App extends Component<Props> { render() { return ( <View style={styles.container}> <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text> <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text> </View> ); } } const styles = StyleSheet.create({ container: { flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF', }, welcome: { fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center', margin: 10, }, instructions: { textAlign: 'center', color: '#333333', marginBottom: 5, }, });
```

Someone can suggest a way to implement the server in my react-native app or a tutorial to solve this problem thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information. Please include relevant code and error logs if available. "a bug" is a bit too vague unfortunately.

Comment: My bug is that when i do run-android, in the display show an error: undefined is not an object (evaluating FPStaticServer.stop)